# Visual Studio VSIX project throws a build error related to pkgdef file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, vsix, vs-extensibility

I created a Visual Studio extension with a couple of item templates. Now, I want to include some code snippets as part of that extension. I followed [Mads Kristensen's post](http://madskristensen.net/post/shipping-visual-studio-snippets-in-an-extension) about the subject. However, when I try to compile the project, I get this error:

Could not determine the FullName of the Assembly at "C:\path\to\file\keys.pkgdef". Could not load file or assembly 'keys.pkgdef' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

I'm developing my extension using Visual Studio 2013.

I think I followed the post carefully, so I don't know what it's missing here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You need to change properties of the keys.pkgdef file:

- Build Action: Content
- Copy to Output Directory: Do not copy
- Include in VSIX: true